# Как отправлять несолько websocket запросов?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

Весь функционал отрабатывает только при первом запросе, то есть если напишешь "что говорит кот?", то вернется "мяу", а при последующих запросах ничего выполняться не будет

index.py:

```py
import asyncio
import websockets
import json


def get_answer_from_artificial_intelligence(text):
    if (text == "что говорит кот?"):
        return "мяу"
    elif (text == "что говорит собака?"):
        return "гав"


async def on_message(message):
    some_res_from_func = get_answer_from_artificial_intelligence(message)
    payload = {"data": some_res_from_func}
    res = json.dumps(payload)

    return res


async def response(websocket, path):
    res = asyncio.create_task(on_message(await websocket.recv()))
    await websocket.send(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server = websockets.serve(response, "localhost", 8001)

    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except websockets.ConnectionClosedOK:
        pass
```

index.js:

```js
const websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8001");

const button = document.querySelector("#button");
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const listOfAnswers = document.querySelector("#listOfAnswers");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    websocket.send(input.value);
});

function insertDataToHtml(data) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(data);

    listOfAnswers.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", `<li class="message">${obj.data}</li>`);
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    websocket.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => { insertDataToHtml(data); });
});
```

Comment: Запрос не отправляется повторно, не обрабатывается на сервере или ответ не приходит?

Comment: ну вот запрос на серв не приходит, при обновлении страницы (отправляю данные через форму) можно отправлять данные снова только один раз, то есть обновил отправил, обновил отправил

Comment: Возможно вы меняете элементы, на которых висят листнеры. Возможно, рвется соединение с сервером после получения ответа. Проверяйте вкладку network, что там творится с вашим соединением. Дополните код HTML разметкой

Answer (score 0):

Просто обвернул в while True:

```py
async def response(websocket, path):
    while True:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        payload = {"data": answer_from_artificial_intelligence(message)}

        res = json.dumps(payload)

        await websocket.send(res)
```